# How to Implement Session Timeout in play framework 2.2.5?

Tags: session-timeout, playframework-2.2

We want to implement session timeout for 10m in our play web application. But I have no idea on how to do this. I followed play 2.2.x documentation and some other web sites's like below mentioned. But it doesn't works for me, how do I do this?

```
Secured.java:

 @Override
public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx) {

    // see if user is logged in
    if (session("userId") == null)
        return null;

    // see if the session is expired
    String previousTick = session("userTime");
    if (previousTick != null && !previousTick.equals("")) {
        long previousT = Long.valueOf(previousTick);
        long currentT = new Date().getTime();
        long timeout = Long.valueOf(Play.application().configuration().getString("sessionTimeout")) * 1000 * 60;
        if ((currentT - previousT) > timeout) {
            // session expired
            session().clear();
            return null;
        } 
    }

    // update time in session
    String tickString = Long.toString(new Date().getTime());
    session("userTime", tickString);

    return User.findById(Long.parseLong(session("userId"))).getUsername();
}

application.conf :
sessionTimeout=10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out above issue. @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class) in controller class was missed.